# How to make a dexterity reference field?

Tags: plone

Using Plone 4.3 (from https://raw.github.com/plock/pins/master/plone-4-3) and trying to make a reference field between two dexterity contents: from `IConsumibleEntry` to `IConsumibleItem`.

If I'm understand correctly, I have to add a **RelationChoice** into `IConsumibleEntry` with a **ObjPathSourceBinder** and then all related `IConsumibleItem` will appear in the add form. I'm following http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/references.html so I did:

```
from mypackage.consumibles.consumible_item import IConsumibleItem

class IConsumibleEntry(form.Schema, IImageScaleTraversable):
    item = RelationChoice(
        title=_(u"Item"),
        source=ObjPathSourceBinder(object_provides=IConsumibleItem.__identifier__),
        required=True,
       )
```

I run plone and created several IConsumibleItem instances, but when I try to create an IConsumibleEntry, there's nothing to chose for the 'item' field.

I tried using other expressions for ObjPathSourceBinder, like chosing by content type, but I still can't get any reference to IConsumibleItem instances.

What else is needed to do to get reference fields populated? Is in needed to modify IConsumibleItem? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you enabled the IReferenceable from plone.app.referenceablebehavior on your content type?

Comment: I don't think IReferenceable is necessary unless you're connecting from archetypes.

Comment: Do you have a custom class for your ConsumibleItems? Is it set up to implement IConsumibleItem?

Comment: All dexterity types were created using zopeskel and don't have any code yet. IConsumibleItem consist of the default line from the template {form.model("models/consumible_item.xml")} and so do ConsumibleItem {grok.implements(IConsumibleItem)}.

Comment: Did you prototype your types TTW? Any chance those ConsumibleItem objects were created before you turned it into a Python package? If so, they won't have the custom class.

Comment: Have you seen this bug report? https://dev.plone.org/ticket/14027? RelationList should work although it is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I prototyped them TTW, but deleted the instances before creating the packages. After reading @steveM comment, I deleted all dexterity types, uninstalled and reinstalled the package, but I still get the same behavior. How could I get a clean state?